# Python Pandas Data Frame save as HTML page

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to save defined in `Python Pandas Data Frame` as `HTML` page. In addition i would like to make this table saved as `HTML` table ability to be filtered by value of any column. Can you please provide possible solution? At the final this should be table saved as `HTML` page. I would like to incorporate this code in my `Python` code. Thank you

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html).

### Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from pandas import *
>>> df = DataFrame({'foo1' : np.random.randn(2),
                    'foo2' : np.random.randn(2)})
>>> df.to_html('filename.html')
```

This will save the following html to `filename.html`.

### Output:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>foo1</th>
      <th>foo2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>-0.223430</td>
      <td>-0.904465</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>0.317316</td>
      <td>1.321537</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. And in case i would like to save this HTML webpage on my C Drive, how can i supply the path? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just `df.to_html('your_filename.html')`?

Comment: @CTZhu, that is indeed more elegant! +1. I actually haven't used this method before, so didn't know that. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Any idea how to also save the styles (CSS)?

Comment: Is there a way to insert an `id` for the `<tbody></tbody>` tag whicle converting DF to `to_html`?

Answer (score 14):

.to_html() also can be used to create html string

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn

df = pd.DataFrame(
    randn(5, 4),
    index = 'A B C D E'.split(),
    columns = 'W X Y Z'.split()
)

str_io = io.StringIO()

df.to_html(buf=str_io, classes='table table-striped')

html_str = str_io.getvalue()

print(html_str)
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>X</th>
      <th>Y</th>
      <th>Z</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <td>0.302665</td>
      <td>1.693723</td>
      <td>-1.706086</td>
      <td>-1.159119</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>B</th>
      <td>-0.134841</td>
      <td>0.390528</td>
      <td>0.166905</td>
      <td>0.184502</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>C</th>
      <td>0.807706</td>
      <td>0.072960</td>
      <td>0.638787</td>
      <td>0.329646</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>D</th>
      <td>-0.497104</td>
      <td>-0.754070</td>
      <td>-0.943406</td>
      <td>0.484752</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>E</th>
      <td>-0.116773</td>
      <td>1.901755</td>
      <td>0.238127</td>
      <td>1.996652</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to write the pandas table without using to_html, also including an external stylesheet:

```
html_string_start = '''
<html>
  <head><title>Report Title</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>
  <body>
'''
html_string_end = '''
  </body>
</html>
'''

with open(r'c:\temp\myfile.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_string_start)
    f.write('<table>')
    for header in dataframe.columns.values:
        f.write('<th>'+str(header)+'</th>')
    for i in range(len(dataframe)):
        f.write('<tr>')
        for col in dataframe.columns:
            value = dataframe.iloc[i][col]    
            f.write('<td>'+str(value)+'</td>')
        f.write('</tr>')
    f.write('</table>')
    f.write(html_string_end)
```