# how to color the pandas table and export it into html

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using python spyder, Python v. 3, I need to color format the `pandas` `DataFrame` table and export it into HTML or image file, in case if export to image, how to make the image height and width of the table and set appropriate font size.
Could someone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

What may be of help is `Styler` available in `pandas`. Have a look at the [tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). Without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is difficult to answer more precisely.

The HTML output is covered by this question: [Python Pandas Data Frame save as HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430009/python-pandas-data-frame-save-as-html-page)